# MySQL spatial query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-spatial

I had a normal table. Now i added a spatial column

```
ALTER TABLE roadData ADD pt POINT ;
```

and now my table has null values :
[image]

Now in MySQL tutorial insert statement is used:

```
INSERT INTO geom VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)'));
```

but i want to  to do it in already existing table removing null values and insert point data based on Latitude and Longitude give in each row. Like

```
INSERT INTO pt VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(latitude longitude)'));
```

and also make a spatial index. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

That's an `UPDATE STATEMENT` and not an `INSERT STATEMENT` , try this:

```
UPDATE geom t
SET t.pt = ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',t.longitude,t.latitude,')'))
```

Comment: thanks sagi actually the answer u told for cross join was taking lot of time. so @bamar said to use spatial so trying that.

Comment: And ALTER TABLE geom ADD SPATIAL INDEX(g); for creating index

Comment: For spatial index : ALTER TABLE roadData ADD SPATIAL INDEX(pt);

Comment: OR CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sp_index ON roadData (pt);

Comment: Why not `SET t.pt = ST_Point(t.longitude, t.latitude)`? Let's make things complicated and waste a lot of resources :-)

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of these functions, I just assumed how the syntax should be to help him:) @kaii